# Vue.js vuex props don't rerender

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex, rerender

I'm using `Vuex` and display data like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div v-for="port in ports">
                <port :port="port"></port>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex';

    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                ports: state => state.ports.ports,
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem that I have now is that when I change the `ports state` in another component it updates the `ports state` correctly but the port in the `v-for` loop is not updated.

How do I make sure the data in the port component `rerenders` correctly as well?

Comment: How are you updating state.ports?  Push? Splice?  Do you really have a state.ports.ports, or should it be state => state.ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue Beginner Gotchas: Why isn't the DOM updating?](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)

> Most of the time, when you change a Vue instance’s data, the view updates. But there are two edge cases:
>
> 1. When you are adding a new property that wasn’t present when the data was observed.
> 2. When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property.

If you are changing your ports data by doing something like this:

`this.ports[0] = 1234;`

Or something like this:

`this.ports[4].property = 'some value';`

Then Vue won't be able to detect that a change occurred. You can get around this pitfall by doing:

`Vue.set(this.ports, 0, 1234);`

Comment: Okay thx, so currently I'm doing this: `this.ports[0] = 1234;` is there another way so it does rerender?

Comment: @Jenssen https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats has recommendations on how to get around Vue's reactivity gotchas, I'll update my answer as well

Comment: Thx you are awesome!

Comment: @Jenssen if my answer solves your problem please click the gray checkmark to accept it, thanks!